# Create an Entity Framework Entity at runtime by string

Tags: entity-framework

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this or if I should even be doing this at all. But I have a method that can be called on certain of my entities. But I want to write this method once to apply to all of the entities because I know they are similar in a certain way.
Is there a way to create an instance of an entity, at runtime, by referencing a string value of that entity type?
So my method would be `GetSomething(Entity e)`
and that can be called on 10 different entities. 
at runtime I have a string "Entity4".
I want to create an instance of that entity and call the `GetSomething()` method on it.
Inside of `GetSomething()` I want to do:

```
using (var db = new TalonEF_test.GISTestProductionEntities())
{
   List<runtimeEntity> es = db.runtimeEntity.Where(o => o.OB == oid).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `Activator.CreateInstance`?  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

"But I want to write this method once to apply to all of the entities because I know they are similar in a certain way."

Write an interface which defines this similarity and then have your entities implement it. When you need to refer to objects which could be any of the entities, use the interface. If you need to run concrete queries against EF, you can call `GetType` on your entity and use that in `DbContext.Set<T>` to get a DbSet reference to run queries against.